# Manage the menu permissions in EasyAdmin

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony2-easyadmin, easyadmin

I'm using Symfony 4 and I would like to show / hide my entities in the menu depending on the roles, but it's impossible.

For example, I tried to override the menu.html.twig of EasyAdmin file but it didn't work.

It only works if I modify a loop directly in the EasyAdmin library but it's bad practice.

Answer (score 3):

try the package `alterphp/easyadmin-extension-bundle` 
it provides this functionality

https://packagist.org/packages/alterphp/easyadmin-extension-bundle

```
easy_admin:
        menu:
            - { label: 'Administrator', role: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN } # Hidden if user is not granted ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN
            - { label: 'App action', route: 'app_action', role: ROLE_ADMIN } # Hidden if user is not granted ROLE_ADMIN
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to override an EasyAdmin template, create a directory `./templates/easy_admin` and put your templates inside.

In your case, just create `./templates/easy_admin/menu.html.twig` and this will override the default menu